# mongoDB test the return value

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I use `mongoDB 3.0.1` in java application, I want to know how I can test the return value of `DBCollection.insert(BasicDBObject)`,

For exemple, if the insert is done show `message1` if not show `message2`.

I see that mongoDB use `WriteResult` as return and these's what I get when I print the `WriteResult`

```
WriteResult insert = dbCollection.insert(basicDBObject);
showMessageDialog(null,insert);

WriteResult{,n=0,updateOfExisting=false, upsertedld=null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle failure or acknowledge insert then,

Refer http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html

You can use it per one write like this:

```
dbCollection.insert(dbObj, WriteConcern.SAFE);
```

If you use `WriteConcern.SAFE` your operation will wait for an acknowledgement from the primary server, so if no exception is raised then you're ok.

You can check using `WriteResult` as well, If `writeResult.getError()` gives `null`, insert is done.

Answer (score 0):

`WriteResult` has method `getN`: https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/. If it returns more than 0, insert is done.